# How can I make sure .asmx JSON results are using Newtonsoft.JSON?

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services, json.net

I have asked a couple of questions about serializing dictionaries and I realized I may not even be using Newtonsoft.JSON in my .ASMX responses!

I have a JSON-emitting webservice class in an .asmx file:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "www.???.com")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ScriptService]
public class ApplicationService : JSONWebServiceBase
{
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public DateTime GetX()
    {
        return DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

To check my JSON, I returned a DateTime property, and using simon_weaver's test this date showed up on the client as

```
{"\/Date(1355627201572)\/"}
```

instead of

```
{"2012-12-15T19:07:03.5247384-08:00"}
```

which tells me the Microsoft serializer is being used and not Newtonsoft.JSON. How do I tell ASP.NET I want to use Newtonsoft?

Comment: depending on your version, you would have to register Newtonsoft as the default script handler

Comment: Thank you @JonathanBates! Digging into how to do that...

Comment: Take a look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763183(v=vs.100).ASPX

Comment: @JonathanBates: Thank you so much for this. I was hoping against hope that I could say "Hey, put this in an answer so I can pick it!" But I'm finding that this doesn't swap-in json.net wholesale - it wants me to code in converters for all the types I want. I just want to 'flip the switch' and have json.net do ALL the jsony-things!

Comment: Unfortunately, web.config's jsonSerialization isn't the answer. That allows you to register custom converters for your types but it all still routes thru the default ASP.NET JSON conversion. What I ended up doing was using JSON.NET and returning it as a string. Not ideal, but it gets me where I need to be.

Answer (score 0):

Check following may work for your 
   `var d = new Date(1245398693390);
    var formattedDate = d.getDate() + "-" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + d.getFullYear();
    var hours = (d.getHours() < 10) ? "0" + d.getHours() : d.getHours();
    var minutes = (d.getMinutes() < 10) ? "0" + d.getMinutes() : d.getMinutes();
    var formattedTime = hours + ":" + minutes;formattedDate = formattedDate + " " + formattedTime;`